# String data to be converted to Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a String

```
string data = "[City, Delhi]&[State, DL]&[Country, IN]";
```

from which I want a dictionary.

The approach I thought was

1. Split on "&"
2. In the resulting Array, parse each element
   2.1 Replace "[" and "]"
   2.2 Insert into the Dictionary

I hate this approach because my string already has "[" and "]" and I should be able to add it directly to Dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by _should be able to add it directly to Dictionary_?

Comment: When I look at elements in the dictionary, I see them in the format "[key, value]". I was hoping to be able to create a dictionary with data "[City, Delhi]", "[State, DL]", "[Country, IN]" from this string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good use case for regular expressions.

```
var d = Regex.Matches(data, @"\[(?<k>[^,]+), (?<v>[^]]+)\]")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["k"].Value, m => m.Groups["v"].Value);
```

Comment: I like your answer. I do have a doubt. Suppose my string is ""[City, Delhi]&[State, DL]&[Country, IN]&Weather, cold]";" and I run the code. I do get the correct output. But I don't have an option to take action if the match fails.

Comment: With that string the fourth value would not match because it doesn't conform to the format you have indicated. For those that do conform, you could enumerate the result of `Regex.Matches()` directly and evaluate each before adding to the dictionary. If you are saying that the square brackets are optional in the data string, then the solution would be slightly different.

Comment: No, I am not saying that square brackets are optional, but since this is user provided data, there is no guarantee. And yes, I agree with the approach you say for validation. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

The approach you describe is probably as good as it's going to get.

A naive implementation (without error handling) would be:

```
var pairs = data.Split('&');

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    var parts = pair.Split(',');

    dict.Add(
        parts[0].TrimStart('['),
        parts[1].TrimStart().TrimEnd(']'));
}
```

Or, using a regular expression to obtain the keys and values:

```
string data = "[City, Delhi]&[State, DL]&[Country, IN]";

var pairs = data.Split('&');

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\[(?<key>.*), (?<value>.*)\]");

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    var match = regex.Match(pair);

    // TODO: Error if match.Success == false ?

    dict.Add(match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Richard. But, I was aiming for something other than what I had described as the possible approach. Can't we do something without doing the Replacing of characters?

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative that makes partial use of regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I am inclined towards Mike's answer. But your answer does provide more flexibility if the regex fails to match. I am wondering if that can be incorporated in Mike's answer.

Comment: It's kind of subjective, and depends on which approach you find the easiest to read and how resilient you want to make it to bad data, and what sort of logging you might want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `linq`

```
string data = "[City, Delhi]&[State, DL]&[Country, IN]";
string[] arr = data.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split('&');
var dict = arr.ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.Split(',')[0], x => x.Split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the replace. That is why I asked the question

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the `replace`.

Comment: You can avoid the `Replace` if you use a regular expression, as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 private static void Splitter()
    {
        string data = "[City, Delhi]&[State, DL]&[Country, IN]";
        Dictionary<string,string> dOutput = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        string[] sArr = data.Split('&');

        var v = from p in sArr
                select p.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',');

         var v2 = (from p in v
                 select p).ToDictionary(item => item[0], item => item[1]);


        Console.WriteLine(v2.Count());

    }
```

v2 is a dictionary object...

Comment: Others, could you please suggest how we can combine these two LINQ statements?